# How do you find a defined relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

So this may be a really simple obvious question, but this is something that kind of trips me up. I'm a beginner at this type of stuff, and still learning.

In my past experience if I see the relation defined, it makes complete sense on how it works, but if a question asks me to find a defined  relation I get confused.

> Now the question starts with Let R be the relation defined on the set
>   of integer pairs by (x1, y1)R(x2, y2) whenever
>
> $x_{1}^{2}$ + $y_{1}^{2}$ = $x_{2}^{2}$ + $y_{2}^{2}$

What's really throwing me off is the integer pairs.

Now besides this example, a general explanation of defining relations would be nice. Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. What type of general explanation are you looking for?

Comment: This relation is an equivalence relation.

Comment: In case like the one above, how do you go on finding the relation? I understand how to find it if it was in the following form R = {(S1, S2) | |S1| < |S2|, S1, S2 ⊆ S}, but I don't understand how to get it from the question above

Comment: It is a relation on $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z.$ So in this case  $$R \subseteq (\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z).$$

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm misunderstanding here. My question is closer to asking how can I get an "example" to work with that is defined by the relation to check if its reflexive ... etc

Comment: Obviously it is reflexive because $x^2+y^2 = x^2 + y^2.$ So $(x,y)\ R\ (x,y).$ It is symmetric because $x^2 + y^2 = y^2 + x^2.$ Try to see that $R$ is also transitive. Try yourself! I give you $5$ minutes.

Comment: Sorry I can edit my answer to check the other properties, but we think you are able!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two elements, in this case integer pairs, are related when the sum of the squares of the elements of each pair are equal. To check properties of the relation consider the elements you are already given: $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. To check if R is reflexive we check if $(x_1,y_1)R(x_1,y_1)$ which is clearly true.

Comment: Please don't help him further @Derek Luna. I earnestly request you. Spoon-feeding something is strongly condemned in this site.

Comment: Yes, that is for the best.